# Which is the correct method for aliasing attributes with FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

Well, I have the following in factories.rb

```
Factory.alias /(.*_)confirmation/, "\1"

Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.new_pass  'asdasdasd'
  f.new_pass_confirmation 'asdasdasd'
end
```

And then when I create the user I do the following:

```
Factory.build(:user, :new_pass => 'something', :new_pass_ => 'something_else')
```

But it throws me an error of:

```
undefined method `new_pass_=` for #<User:0x1234567>
```

Shouldn't FactoryGirl convert the new_pass_ to new_pass_confirmation?

Answer (score 1):

Aliases in factory_girl are used to prevent two attributes from clashing with each other. The classic example is an association vs a foreign key: if your factory defines a "user" association and you override it by passing "user_id," the "user_id" should take precedence.

If you wanted the password confirmation to override password, you'd use this alias:

```
Factory.alias /(.*)_confirmation/, "\1"
```

It sounds like you want the password confirmation to default to the password, which you can do like this:

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.new_pass  'asdasdasd'
  f.new_pass_confirmation { |u| u.new_pass }
end
```

In the new syntax, you can leave out the block arguments:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    new_pass  'asdasdasd'
    new_pass_confirmation { new_pass }
  end
end
```